# How can I inherit from psycopg2?

Tags: python, inheritance, psycopg2

I'm trying inherit psycopg2 like this:

```
import psycopg2

class myp(psycopg):
    pass

ii = myp
ii.connect(database = "myDataBase", user = "myUser", password="myPassword")
```

Then it throws an error:

```
class myp(psycopg2._psycopg):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Is it possible to inherit from psycopg2 library?

EDIT:
I want to use different databases, so I just have to change the class MyDatabase. something like a wrapper.
example:

```
import psycopg2

class MyDatabase(psycopg2):
    def connect(self):
        #do some stuff
        return psycopg2.connect(database = "myDataBase", user = "myUser",   password="myPassword")
```

for mysqldb
    import MySQLdb

```
class MyDatabase(MySQLdb)
    def connect(self):
        #do some stuff
        return psycopg2.connect(database = "myDataBase", user = "myUser", password="myPassword")
```

and derived class
    class MyDataBaseApp(MyDatabase):
        def add(self, myObjectClass):
            db = MyDatabase()
            cn = None

```
        try:
            cn = db.connect()
            cur = cn.cursor()
            cur.execute ("INSERT ...",(myObjectClass.parameter1, myObjectClass.parameter2))
            cn.commit()
        except MyDatabase.DatabaseError, e:
            print e
            if cn:
                cn.rollback()
        finally:
            if cn:
                cn.close()
```

but according to the documentation I have to do it another way, suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with psycopg

**Update**

Seems [the documentation recommends](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#subclassing-cursor) to subclass `psycopg2.extensions.connection`. Then, `connect()` is a factory function that can still be used to create new connections, but you have to provide your class as a factory, again [according to the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect)

Full code may have to look more like (untested):

```
import psycopg2

class myp(psycopg2.extensions.connection):
    pass

ii = connect(connection_factory=myp,
             database = "myDataBase", user = "myUser", password="myPassword")
```

**Update 2**

With the updated approach, you're trying to build new classes with different/divergent interfaces. Often, composition is better than inheritance, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did your suggestion but still not working

Comment: If we have to guess at the errors, we cannot help you. Please post the errors. What changed? What's your exact code?

Comment: the same error as above. 
`import psycopg2
class myp(psycopg2.psycopg1):
    pass

ii = myp()
ii.connect(database = "myDataBase", user = "myUser", password="myPassword")`

Comment: I will try to implement your suggestions. thank you very much!